# Tight bounds on $E^TF+F^TE$

Tags: inequality, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

I know that I can upper bound the term $E^TF+F^TE \preceq \alpha^2E^TE+\alpha^{-2}
F^TF$ where $\alpha\neq 0$. I want to find a tighter bound but again with some positive semidefinite terms! thanks!

Comment: 1) "I know that" : please give references to this inequality (obtained by setting $G=\alpha E-\frac{1}{\alpha}F$ and expanding the RHS of $0\preceq G^TG$) 2) What have you attempted ? 3) Please say that $\preceq$ is the Loewner order on positive semi-definite matrices (little advice: always give the biggest amount of information)

Comment: No comment, 6 hours later ?